# Docker maven plugin

Tags: rest, maven, docker, virtualization

Docker plugin which I found (spotify/docker-maven-plugin) use native `docker` application, but as far as I understand `docker` is just an REST API client which "redirects" commands to docker daemon process.
It's especially true in case if I use docker on Windows machine and docker daemon works on Linux in Virtual Box.

So, does any docker-maven-plugin exist which doesn't require native `docker` application and just "talking" with docker daemon without any intermediaries?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Unclear what your problem is. Are you trying to run a Maven build within a docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't require a native `docker` application, so much as knowing where the docker daemon is.

#### Docker-Maven-Plugin

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin):

> By default the plugin will try to connect to docker on localhost:2375. Set the DOCKER_HOST environment variable to connect elsewhere.

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<host>:2375
```

This is how the client knows where Docker daemon is. Docker-Maven-Plugin respects this (and other) Docker environment variables to know where Docker resides, whether it be native, in a VM running on a hypervisor like VirtualBox locally, or on a completely remote server.

#### Docker Machine

If you're using Docker Machine, these environment variables are set when you run :

```
$ docker-machine env default
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://172.16.62.130:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/<yourusername>/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval "$(docker-machine env default)"

$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

The documentation for Docker Machine:

[Create & Connect to Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#/create-a-machine)

#### Docker for Windows

If you're on Windows, you may find it helpful to use the native client Docker to give everything a more native experience.

[Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

you also can use the mantioned docker-maven-plugin like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.13</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>yourImageName</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>
                <dockerCertPath>/Users/your_user/.docker/machine/machines/default</dockerCertPath>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Important are these two tags:

```
<dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>
<dockerCertPath>/Users/your_user/.docker/machine/machines/default</dockerCertPath>
```

I am using a dockerfile, which path you have to define with this tag:

```
<dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
```

Now you can build your jar and generate docker image via:

mvn package docker:build